# No suitable ServiceConnectorCreator found error during push to CloudFoundry

Tags: java, spring-cloud, cloud-foundry

Error log:

> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method
>   'mysqlEntityManagerFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration':
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'mysqlDataSource' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [com/multipledbexamplegroup/multipledbexampleartifact/config/BookingDBConfig.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'mysqlDataSource'
>   threw exception; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.cloud.CloudException: No suitable
>   ServiceConnectorCreator found: service id=aurora-service, service info
>   type=org.springframework.cloud.service.BaseServiceInfo, connector
>   type=interface javax.sql.DataSource    2019-03-25T17:32:50.46+0530
>   [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.22.RELEASE]
>   2019-03-25T17:32:50.46+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.22.RELEASE]
>   2019-03-25T17:32:50.46+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1178)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.22.RELEASE]
>   2019-03-25T17:32:50.46+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:107

Comment: I have usedcbelow in gradle file:compile(group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-spring-service-connector')
 compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector'

Comment: It doesn't seem to know how to create the service bean. What does your `cf env` output (sanitized of course) look like? Can you include that here?